# Haskell Read from file and parse string into words

Tags: haskell

When in ghci mode I can type this line :

```
map read $ words "1 2 3 4 5" :: [Int]
```

and get 
[1,2,3,4,5]

When I make a file named splitscan.hs containing this line:

```
    map read $ words scan :: [Float]
```

I get this error:

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( splitscan.hs, splitscan.o )

```
splitscan.hs:1:1: error:
    Invalid type signature: map read $ words str :: ...
    Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
  |
1 | map read $ words str :: [Float]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When I do this:

```
import System.IO

main = do
    scan <- readFile "g924310_b1_copy.txt"
    map read $ words scan :: [Float]
    putStr scan
```

I get :

```
readscan.hs:5:5: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: IO Float
        Actual type: [Float]
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: map read $ words scan :: [Float]
      In the expression:
        do scan <- readFile "g924310_b1_copy.txt"
             map read $ words scan :: [Float]
           putStr scan
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do scan <- readFile "g924310_b1_copy.txt"
                   map read $ words scan :: [Float]
                 putStr scan
```

The question is, how do implement the ghci line such that I can get all the words from the scan and make a list of them that I can later fit regressions, add constants to etc.

Comment: Wouldn't use `scan` as a variable name as it resembles too much to `scanl`, `scanr`.

Answer (score 6):

In Haskell, variables are immutable. So `map read $ words scan` doesn't change the variable `scan`; it returns a new value. You need to use this new value if you want to do something with it.

```
import System.IO

main = do
    scan <- readFile "g924310_b1_copy.txt"
    let scan' = map read $ words scan :: [Float]
    print scan'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
floats :: String -> [Float]
floats = fmap read . words

main :: IO ()
main = print =<< fmap floats readFile "g924310_b1_copy.txt"
```